# MvxListView will not bind

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am having the strangest error:
I have a page with an MvxListView in it here is the partial layout:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
            android:id="@+id/RatingsList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Path=Dishes"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/userpagedishtemplate"
            style="@style/ToolBarImage"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />
```

When the corresponding ViewModel gets loaded I get the following error:

```
[MvxBind]  24.32 Unable to bind: source property source not found Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken on RestaurantPageViewModel
```

The property Dishes exists in the viewmodel:

```
List<DishViewModel> _dishes = new List<DishViewModel>();    
    List<DishViewModel> Dishes
    {
        get
        {
            return _dishes;
        }
        set
        {
            _dishes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => Dishes);
        }
    }
```

And I have a method that fills the list with items:

```
private void LoadDishesFromWeb()
    {
        List<Dish> dishes = CommunicationManager.Restaurnats.GetDishListForRestaurnat (Restaurant.ID);
        foreach (var item in dishes)
        {
            Dishes.Add (new DishViewModel (item));
        }
    }
```

I have the same logic working in a different view in my app only with different types

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block:

```
List<DishViewModel> Dishes 
{
    get
    {
        return _dishes;
    }
    set
    {
        _dishes = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged (() => Dishes);
    }
}
```

produces a `private` Dishes property - try adding a `public` word in front of it